# Why isn't all the data getting loaded into my MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, csv

So I have a file of Twitter data that looks like this

```
Robert_Aderholt^&^&^2013-06-12 18:32:02^&^&^RT @financialcmte: In 2012, the Obama Admin published 1,172 new regulations totaling 79,000 pages. 57 were expected to have costs of at...
Robert_Aderholt^&^&^2013-06-12 13:42:09^&^&^The Administration's idea of a 'recovery' is 4 million fewer private sector jobs than the average post WWII recovery http://t.co/gSVW0Q8MYK
Robert_Aderholt^&^&^2013-06-11 13:51:17^&^&^As manufacturing jobs continue to decrease, its time to open new markets #4Jobs http://t.co/X2Mswr1i43
```

(The ^&^&^ words are separators, and I chose that separator because it's unlikely to occur in any of the tweets.)

This file is 90663 lines long (I checked by typing "wc -l tweets_parsed-6-12.csv").

However, when I load them into the table, I only get a table with 40456 entries:

```
mysql> source ../code/tweets2tables.sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

Query OK, 40456 rows affected, 2962 warnings (0.81 sec)
Records: 40456  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 2962

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweets;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|    40456 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Why is that?  I deleted all lines that didn't contain ^&^&^ so I didn't think there was any funny business going on with the data, but I could be wrong.

My loading code is

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tweets;

CREATE TABLE tweets (
    twitter_id      VARCHAR(20),
    post_date       DATETIME,
    body            VARCHAR(140)
);

LOAD DATA
    LOCAL INFILE 'tweets_parsed-6-12.csv'
    INTO TABLE tweets
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^&^&^'
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (twitter_id, post_date, body);
```

Comment: Do any of the lines have internal linebreaks `\n`? You have them `ENCLOSED BY '"'`, but your data as above does not enclose all fields with quotes. In that case you should do `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`

Comment: You could dump the data back out to a file, make sure it's formatted/sorted correctly, and then run a diff, looking for any patterns in the missing entries.

Comment: Also note that you have 2962 warnings.  `SHOW WARNINGS;` to see what those are...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Oh is that what ENCLOSED BY means?  I just copied the LOAD DATA code from some StackExchange post :P  Anyway that is good to know, I deleted that line and got the right answer!  Thanks!

Comment: Wait now I have 6319 warnings.  Shit.

Comment: @ilovestackoverflow The warnings might be harmless though, or may be data truncations, etc.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Yeah it looks like they're data truncations.  I increased the "body" field to 150 characters, but I'm still getting data truncations, which is weird since Twitter posts are supposed to be 140 characters long.

Comment: Woot I got to 90663 rows and Warnings: 0.  Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: @ilovestackoverflow I don't know how twitter treats links, hashtags, etc - whether they count toward the limit. Kick it up to 255 or use a `TEXT` column

Answer (score 1):

The lines that weren't loaded probably contained the `"` character. If you specify that your fields are terminated with `"`, the quotes inside of them should be escaped like this - `""` (double quotes).

The `OPTIONALLY` keyword before `ENCLOSED` may help.